# Calculating the number of children and sibiling of a process in the kernel mode

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I am a bit confused about calculating the number of children and sibling of a process. I have a struct of a process info, which is as follows:

```
struct process_info {
    long pid; /* Process ID */
    char name[/* Some size. */]; /* Program name of process */
    long state; /* Current process state */
    long uid; /* User ID of process owner */
    long nvcsw; /* # voluntary context switches */
    long nivcsw; /* # involuntary context switches */
    long num_children; /* # children process has */
    long num_siblings; /* # sibling process has */
};
```

And I have a function that fills up and return the process information from the above struct:

```
struct process_info get_process_info(struct task_struct* this_task) {
    struct process_info res;
    int temp_num_children = 0;
    int temp_num_sibling = 0;
    struct list_head* traverse_ptr;

    res.pid = this_task->pid;
    memcpy(res.name, this_task->comm, /* The size of the string declared before the struct above. */);
    res.state = this_task->state;
    res.uid = this_task->cred->uid.val;
    res.nvcsw = this_task->nvcsw;
    res.nivcsw = this_task->nivcsw;


    list_for_each(traverse_ptr, &(this_task->children)) {
        ++temp_num_children;
    }


    list_for_each(traverse_ptr, &(this_task->sibling)) {
        ++temp_num_sibling;
    }
    res.num_children = temp_num_children;
    res.num_siblings = temp_num_sibling;

    return res;
}
```

Filling out the all the information except the number of both the children and sibling is very straight forward, since they are in the struct task_list instance already. However, I want to calculate the number of children and sibling using list_for_each function, but I don't know if this is the right way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

children and sibling of struct task_struct links all the children and siblings of said task, so yes, what you are doing is right.

Comment: Also, is this task counted with its siblings or no, because my counter for each process_info (I'm storing the process info of each process and its ancestors in an array in a different function, which uses this function to get info) is always counting at least 1? Is this correct?

Comment: sibling are the processes that shares the same parent, so in most case it's 1. So you verify by forking several processes, and then call your function in one of the children.